# Payment method Check / Money Order is not displaying in checkout page

Tags: php, magento, paypal, payment-gateway, magento-1.9

Payment method Check / Money Order is enabled from admin panel, but it is not showing on frontend Checkout step "Payment information".
I am currently using Magento 1.9.1

Payment method Check/Money Order option is missing in payment method step.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the values from Minimum Order Total and Maximum Order Total.

Then clean cache. If still not working then create logs. You can use use log code inside file: `app\code\core\Mage\Payment\Model\Method\Checkmo.php`

Answer (score 0):

Remove Max Order Total and Min Order Total and flush magento cache and check it